# About apache ignite IgnitePredicate<EventAdapter> interface

Tags: ignite

I am using **IgnitePredicate** interface to get to know when the cache had modified(put or remove).

```
@Override
    public boolean apply(EventAdapter e) {
        if (e instanceof CacheEvent) {
            CacheEvent cacheEvent = (CacheEvent)e;
            if (e.type() == EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT) {
                MyClass obj = (MyClass)cacheEvent.newValue();//line 1
                MyClass obj = ((BinaryObject)cacheEvent.newValue()).deserialize()//line 2
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I wanna get the new data put into the cache by the codes above.

At first, I am using the code line 1, and it works.

Afterward, I found it cause an error "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl cannot be cast to MyClass".So I change the code to line 2.But it cause another exception "MyClass cannot be cast to o.a.i.i.b.BinaryObjectImpl".And the newValue is a MyClass object.

I wanna know why sometimes it is a BinaryOjbectImpl and sometimes it is a MyClass object. Or it depended on something I do not know. Or something wrong in my code.

Thanks.
Best regards.

Comment: I found it may be depended on whether the node joined others or other nodes join into it(cluster).

Comment: For example, Node A started, and Node B finds A and joins into A as a cluster. Put an object into the cache. A works ok. B cause an exception"java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl cannot be cast to MyClass".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general events are being triggered not only for one exact cache but for multiple caches. `CacheEvent` contains `cacheName` as a property. As far as I can see you don't filter them according `cacheName`. So it's possible that some cache is being used with binary storage enabled. You can get more information [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller#binaryobject-cache-api).

For example cache `A` is created as:

```java
IgniteCache<Integer, BinaryObject> binaryCache = ignite.cache("A").withKeepBinary();
```

Another one (cache `B`) is created as:

```java
IgniteCache<Integer, SomeClass> cache = ignite.cache("B");
```

By the way I suppose that the right way to achieve the desired behavior is to use continuous [queries](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries).

Comment: Thank you. But all caches in my code created are like cache B.

Comment: I will try with filtering the cachename.

Comment: Hi, I have added the cachename filtering, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it possible to share a reproducer that shows such behavior?

Comment: By the I suppose that the right way to achieve the desired behavior is to use continuous queries (https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries).

Comment: Hi, Vladimir Pligin, thank you very much. I have read the article, it helps me a lot.